# How to get number of delegators of a pool?

Tags: stake-pool, cardano-db-sync

Using cardano-db-sync, I want to get the number of delegators given a pool_id.

For example, this pool has 22 delegators.
https://cardanoscan.io/pool/18109d01af0c5c4495a64a9de061ad621156729afc699128c0ceee0e?tab=delegators

However, when I used the following query, the result did not match. The following query returns 66 unique values of stake_address.hash_raw.

```
select pool_hash.view,stake_address.hash_raw::text, stake_address.view,  
delegation.active_epoch_no, delegation.slot_no
from delegation, pool_hash, stake_address
where delegation.pool_hash_id = pool_hash.id and delegation.addr_id =stake_address.id 
and pool_hash.view ='pool1rqgf6qd0p3wyf9dxf2w7qcddvgg4vu56l35ez2xqemhqun2gn7y'
```

I want to ask that

1. It seems the the table `delegation` also contains the delegation history, not only the delegation at current time? If so, which table should I use to be able to filter out to get only the number of current delegators.
2. How can I get the number of delegators w.r.t a pool_id

   (2.1) at the current epoch

   (2.2) for each epoch

Answer (score 4):

> It seems the the table delegation also contains the delegation history, not only the delegation at current time?

Yes, that makes the `delegation` table a bit of a pain in the neck for something like this.

Its probably easier to use the `epoch_stake` table. The simplest query would be something like (choose the epoch you are interested in):

```
select epoch_no, pool_id, count(*), sum (amount) as delegated from epoch_stake
    where epoch_no = 362 group by (pool_id, epoch_no) ; 

 epoch_no | pool_id | count |   delegated    
----------+---------+-------+----------------
      362 |    3081 |     2 |       70449031
      362 |     361 |    10 |   264344058414
      362 |    1286 |    34 |   709992195312
      362 |     560 |     1 |      507621786
      362 |    5214 |    10 |  4983514457611
      362 |    4090 |     3 |     1893354467
      362 |    4791 |     9 |   335768752617
      362 |    3159 |     3 |     5945300103
      362 |    5215 |    99 |  1358232546301
      362 |    4765 |     7 | 13999900770537
      362 |    2623 |    52 |  3429179709353
...
```

The pool fingerprint (ie `pool1rqgf6qd0...`) can be obtained with a join on the `pool_hash` table like you have in your example. Also, note that unfortunately, the `epoch_stake` table for epoch `N` is updated late in epoch `N - 1` (I think).

To get the delegation history for a pool, something like this should work:

```
select epoch_no, pool_id, count(*), sum (amount) as delegated from epoch_stake
    where pool_id = 3081 group by (pool_id, epoch_no) order by epoch_no asc  ; 
 epoch_no | pool_id | count |   delegated    
----------+---------+-------+---------------
      258 |    3081 |     2 |      70643792
      259 |    3081 |     4 | 2105455092524
      260 |    3081 |     4 | 2105455092524
      261 |    3081 |     4 | 2105455092524
      262 |    3081 |     4 | 2105455092524
...
```

A simple join with the `pool_hash` table will allow you to use the pool fingerprint.

Comment: Thanks so much. You save my day.

Comment: I would like to ask a follow-up question.
From this epoch_stake table, I can get the delegated amount for each stake_address per epoch.
Does this delegated amount already include the reward? 
Or I need to add the reward mount (from reward table) to get proper delegated amount?

Comment: No, the reward for epoch `N` is not included in the delegated amount for that epoch because the rewards earned in epoch `N` are not distributed until epoch `N + 2`. From this I hope you can see that you should not add the reward amount to the delegated amount.

Comment: I see. Thank you. So the delegated amount for epoch N (in epoch_stake table)  already includes rewards for epoch N-2? Or not include yet?

Comment: Yes, the delegated amount for epoch `N` already includes rewards earned in epoch `N - 2` and earlier.

Comment: Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

The poor man's way to find out is to go to [pool.pm](https://pool.pm) and type in the pool of interest ticker, and at the top header is the number of delegators.